# Как авторизоваться в ВК с помощью selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, вконтакте, авторизация

Пытаюсь залогиниться в ВК через selenium

```
    driver.get("https://vk.me/chat")
    # начинается попытка логина в случае редиректа
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".login_header"))
        )
        login = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
        login.send_keys(USERNAME_VK)

        login = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
        login.send_keys(PASSWORD_VK)
        login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        driver.get("https://vk.me/chat")
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

Каждый раз ВК требует ввести код подтверждения, что ломает всю автоматизацию. Есть ли возможность это обойти?

Comment: Сделать отдельный профиль браузера. В нем авторизоваться. Указывать профиль в драйвере селениума, чтобы не авторизовываться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помогло добавление профиля и юзер-агента в опции драйвера, спасибо.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + PROFILE)
options.add_argument("user-agent=" + USER_AGENT)

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
```